# How to import a resource from the same package?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Good morning everyone,

I've been trying for hours to manage to import a resource and failing.
I hope that I'm doing something wrong and you would have an answer :-)

I'm trying to use a groovy shared library in Jenkins.
I followed the directory structure described in the documentation:

```
(root)
+- src                     # Groovy source files
|   +- org
|       +- foo
|           +- Bar.groovy  # for org.foo.Bar class
+- vars
|   +- foo.groovy          # for global 'foo' variable
|   +- foo.txt             # help for 'foo' variable
+- resources               # resource files (external libraries only)
|   +- org
|       +- foo
|           +- bar.json    # static helper data for org.foo.Bar
```

In my case, I have a resource called resultsProcessor.html (located where bar.json is). This is an html template.
I also have a class called ResultsProcessor.groovy (located where Bar.groovy is). In this class I want to get the content of resultsProcessor.html to render it.

So far it's been many hours and a lot of frustration!
I tried using different things, including

```
this.getClass().getResource("resultsProcessor.html")
this.getClass().getResource("/resultsProcessor.html")
this.getClass().getResource("org/foo/resultsProcessor.html")
```

And some variants using getClassLoader etc.
Everytime I get "null".

Do you know what I'm missing here?
Do I somehow need to add the resources to a search path?

In general I'm struggling a lot with import / class path. For example, why do some import fail locally using the groovy console while they're not problem when running on Jenkins. If you have relevant documentation or article to advise I would appreciate :-)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: about resources: 

 1. the directory `resources` must be in your classpath 
 2. `this.getClass().getResource("/org/foo/resultsProcessor.html")`

What IDE are you using? and `groovy console` from IDE or from groovy? Could you also provide an example of failed import in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to [dagget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276664/daggett) for helping here.
I was developing using directly the groovy Console from groovy.
In the end I installed, IntelliJ IDE. Once I marked the "resources" directory as the root resources directory, my code worked right away locally. So I guess I am not setting the classpath properly when using the groovy console.

It still fails on Jenkins. getResource returns null. But this is another story. At least now I'm unblocked.

Thanks!